# CSS Positioning of a "Read more" link on top of article preview

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am having an issue positioning a "**read more**" type of *link* above an article preview `div` i have created.
I display the article in a *rectangular box* with defined `height` and `width` and have it set to `overflow:hidden`. I have then added a *link* and given it a `z-index of +1`, `position:absolute`, `right:0` and `bottom 0`.

My hopes were that it would be pushed into the bottom right corner of the `div` and overlay the preview of the article text. Unfortunately it is dissapearing. I assume it is been placed at the bottom right of the whole article and is therefore hidden from view. Try as i might I can not get my brain to kick in for a solution.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
.articlepreviewlayout{
height:200px;
width: 669px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 2px solid #ff6600;
margin: 10px;
}

.articlepreviewlayout img{
width: auto;
height: 200px;
}

.articlepreviewlayout a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #ff6600;
}

.articlepreviewlayout p{
font-size: 75%;
}

.articlepreviewlayout a.readmore{
color: #000000;
z-index: +1;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

And the html/php:

```
    <div class="articlepreviewlayout">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title = 'Simple Ideas For Your Website Logo.'")
or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); 

echo "<a class='readmore' href='".$row['link']."'>Read Full Article</a>";
echo "<img src='".$row['images']."' align='left' />";
echo "<h3><a href='".$row['link']."'>";
echo $row['title']."</a></h3>";
echo "<h6>Author: ".$row['author']."</h6>";
echo "<h6>Published:".$row['timestamp']."</h6>";
echo "<p>".$row['content']."</p>";
?>
</div><!-- articlepreviewlayout -->
```

I appreciate any help with this. I have been searching like mad for a solution and either nobody has asked this before or i just can't think of the right search terms.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be confused on what you want but I created a simple jsfiddle to see if I'm correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc2Es/1/

Here I have the html that puts #main as the article and has a #readMore on the bottom right hand corner of the #main div:

```
#main {
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#readMore {
    width:300px;
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}


<div id="main">
    <div id="mainContent">
        There is the text that shows within the div.  I am writing content in the div so that it fills with content.  There is the text that shows within the div.  I am writing content in the div so that it fills with content.  There is the text that shows within the div.  I am writing content in the div so that it fills with content.  There is the text that shows within the div.
    </div>

    <div id="readMore">Read More</div>
</div>
```

Obviously you'll have to fill in the information with your php but this is the main idea.  Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for so I can better understand what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job. It's working great now anlooks great with a gradient background and some border radius. Also thanbks @haidinhtran. I feel like slapping myself for not figuring the relative positioning out. All the things i tried that should have been the first. Thanks for your time guys I will try and pay it forward on here where I can.

Answer (score 0):

The DIV container position must be relative;

```
.articlepreviewlayout {
position: relative;
height:200px;
width: 669px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 2px solid #ff6600;
margin: 10px;
}
```